# Generating path vectors from point-to-point data

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a list of point-to-point $(x,y)$ positions representing a path. I would like to convert these points to a list of vectors consisting of straight segments $\{L\}$ and turn vectors $\{r, \theta\}$, where turns are represented by arcs on a circle. For example, the set of points

```
(0,0), (0,10), (5,15), (10,10), (10,0)
```

would be converted to

```
(10), (5,180°), (10)
```

[image: point-to-point-and-vector-representation-example]

Note that the start point and heading angle of a new vector is the end point/heading of the previous vector. The only way I can change the direction of the path is by conducting a circular turn. The original point data is generated using similar rules.

What is the best way of doing this?

---

This is how I'm currently approaching the problem:

1. $P_0$ to $P_1$ is assumed to be a straight vector (not necessarily correct). This gives us a heading angle $\phi_{0}$.
2. If the heading angle from $P_1$ to $P_2$ is different from the heading angle from $P_0$ to $P_1$ (i.e. $\phi_0 \ne \phi_1$), initiate a turn segment.

   - The position of $P_1$ is saved. $P_1$ is the endpoint of the first straight vector, and the startpoint of the turn vector.
   - $P_2$ is the next point in the turn vector
3. By necessity, $P_3$ must also be in the turn vector (it takes 3 points to identify a distinct circle).

   - From these three points, we can identify a distinct circumcenter and circumradius, $\{x,y,r\}_0$, of the circle representing this turn.
4. For each new point after, we determine whether it is part of the same turn by calculating the new point's error. This is where it gets problematic:

   - There may be some "fuzziness" in the positions of the points. This makes the original $\{x,y,r\}_0$ potentially inaccurate, because locally the first 3 points may curve one way but the overall trend of the turn is to inflect the other way:
   - [image: circle-fitting]
   - To overcome this, I use the Modified Least Squares method introduced by [Umbach and Jones](http://www.cs.bsu.edu/homepages/kerryj/kjones/circles.pdf) to determine a new circumcenter and circumradius from the original 3 points and the next new point, $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4$.
   - I continue to calculate new circumcenters and circumradii for each new point. If they are all part of the same turn, they will tend towards a single circumcenter and circumradius, $\{x,y,r\}_1$.
   - At the same time, I track the distance from a new point to the current circumcenter. If the distance from a new point, $P_n$ to the circumcenter exceeds the circumradius by more than, say, 5%, then the turn has ended ($P_{n-1}$ is the last point in the turn).
5. The circumradius becomes the radius $r$ used to define the turn vector. The turn angle $\theta$ is simply the angle between the first point in the turn, $P_1$, the circumcenter, and the last point in the turn, $P_{n-1}$.
6. Determine whether the vector from $P_{n-1}$ to $P_n$ is straight or a turn by going to **Step 2**. Repeat until all points have been examined.

Unfortunately this does not seem to work for all cases, and my results don't seem to sufficiently match my original data. It also seems needlessly complex. I'm wondering if there's a better, non-bruteforce, less naive way of approaching this problem.

Comment: I think you need to define your possible results before you define possible algorithms to compute them. Your current criteria aren't 100% clear, and they appear to allow no solutions for certain cases  and multiple sokutions in other cases, such as the example given.

Comment: The output needs to be a continuous and differentiable path (i.e. the heading angle is preserved between ending one vector and starting another). The only way to change the heading angle is by initiating a circular turn. I can guarantee that each turn in the point-to-point data consists of at least 3 points. One hopes that the original data set of point-to-point paths was generated using similar rules, but even if they weren't I'm only looking for the best-fit path. Does that help?

Comment: Yes; but ow do you define best fit? Minimal total length of the path?

Comment: In my current implementation, via a least squares fit for straight segments. For turn segments, I use the Modified Least Squares equation introduced in the link above to obtain a circumcenter and circumradius, then determine if a new point is "acceptable enough" by comparing its geometric distance with the circumradius. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, however.

Comment: If you don't define correctness, you'll never know ...

Comment: What I meant was that I'm not sure if this is the best approach. I've defined "correctness" as previously stated: with least squares for line segments and MLS + geometric distance for turns. This only works for some cases, which suggests to me that there might be better alternatives, both for definitions of "correctness" and for implementations of an algorithm.